# WordPress custom post type custom rewrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

We are building out a property management site and we are using a custom post type for upcoming projects with its own taxonomy services. Currently we are filtering the category archive page using the the following structure `https://partridge.dnhq.com.au/services/structural?tag=heritage` I am attempting to rewrite the permalink structure to eliminate the `?tag=value` parameter and display like `https://partridge.dnhq.com.au/services/structural/heritage`

I currently have a rewrite rule in place, however it is still resulting in a 404.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {    
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        //'index.php?&category_name=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]',
        'index.php?post_type=projects&services=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rule' );
```

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: I haven't read your code yet, but just to make sure, you've flushed the permalinks after each change?